# DacPac is too big error - but my file is only 406kb

Tags: sql, azure

I am trying to upload my database to SQL Azure. I have created the DCA package and started the upload process. However, I immediately get the following error: Specified DacPac is too big. Maximum allowed DacPac size is '5242880' bytes.

I dont understand why I am getting this error when the upload file is 406KB.

Comment: +1 I am getting the same problem and my dacpac is around 300KB. However, If I connect to the server in SSMS though and do Deploy Dacpac using the wizard there it seems to work, so this will be my workaround for now.

Comment: I have a dacpac that is 12 MB and which took 45 minutes to generate within VisualStudio 2012. It is for a production Microsoft Dynamics GP  (formerly Great Plains) customer database.  I was amazed that I was able to get the dacpac created in the first place, but it appears to be useless in any of the tools. Now I see that even Windows Azure has a 5 MB limit. I will see if I can post this as a question, but I am commenting here in case it's a waste of time.