# Unable to add database reference for dacpac in Visual Studio 2012 - OutOfMemoryException

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, out-of-memory, data-tier-applications, dacpac

I have a dacpac that is 12 MB and which took 45 minutes to generate within VisualStudio 2012. It is for a production Microsoft Dynamics GP (formerly Great Plains) customer database. I was amazed that I was able to get the dacpac created in the first place, but it appears to be useless in any of the development tools (Visual Studio 2012 or SSMS 2012). Now I see that even Windows Azure has a 5 MB limit ([DacPac is too big error - but my file is only 406kb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220530/dacpac-is-too-big-error-but-my-file-is-only-406kb)).

I am receiving OutOfMemoryException even in the SSMS 2012 IDE.

[image: SSMS 2012]

For what it is worth, the .model temp file grew to 1.5 GB while Visual Studio 2012 created the dacpac.

Any ideas how I might be able to add the database reference in Visual Studio or import the dacpac into SQL Server (perhaps in stages)? Is there just a hard limit to what the tools can use?

Comment: It appears that this model is so big due to encrypted database objects. I ran across an error in another context that complained about encrypted database objects. This is the only explanation I have derived thus far for the size bloat of the DACPAC.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been trying to import a database from a bacpac file and was getting a similar OutOfMemoryException.  However after I closed and reopened management studio it worked OK.